# Activation function selection for autoencoders

Tags: autoencoders

I am running an autoencoder model and have to select my activation function. I have structured data (i.e. not an image) which comprises continuous variables which have a range of -4 to +4 for each continuous variable.

Which activation function should I use for this?

As background, I am using autoencoders as a dimension reduction tool to be create new predictor variables to be used for supervised classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normalize the input in the [-1,1] range and then use ReLU for the hidden layers and a tanh for the output layer. Having all the variables in the same range also make it a bit easier.

I find [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369246/autoencoders-and-linear-activation-output-function?rq=1) very relevant for your question.